# Excel - Counting value occurrence in two separate columns

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

```
| Start Time | End Time |  
| 2300       | 100      |  
| 400        | 2300     |
```

etc..

So I have two columns w/ thousands of rows, of time data (which is stored as whole numbers not as times) and I need to count how many rows either start OR end between 2000 and 800 (8pm and 8am). If it was one column, or only rows that start AND end between that period I could do it but I'm at a loss currently. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I both are between the times I assume you only want to count it as 1 and not 2?

Comment: Yeah, so if each row is an event I want to count it as one event rather than it being counted twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A4>2000)+(A2:A4<800)+(B2:B4>2000)+(B2:B4<800)>0)*1)
```

[image]

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid thank you comments, but I feel like you're my excel guardian angel, you've been super helpful

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work:

`=IF(AND(A1>=2000,B1<=800),"1","")`